# Collection being modified during loop when there is no way it can be C#

Tags: c#, collections, invalidoperationexception, concurrentmodification

The following code's foreach statement throws an InvalidOperationException saying "Collection has been modified. Enumeration operation cannot execute." I don't see how this is possible, seeing as colors can never be modified after it's initialization.

```
Dictionary<Color, int> colorDictionary = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
//Put stuff in colorDictionary...
int currentBest = 257;
Color replaceColor = Color.Empty;
Dictionary<Color, int>.KeyCollection colors = colorDictionary.Keys;
foreach (Color c in colors)
{
    if (colorDictionary[c] == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (ColorDistance(color, c) < currentBest)
    {
        replaceColor = c;
        colorDictionary[c]--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> I don't see how this is possible, seeing as colors can never be modified after it's initialization.

It's a view on the dictionary's keys... and you're modifying the dictionary here:

```
colorDictionary[c]--;
```

Admittedly that's not actually adding or removing any keys - but it's modifying the dictionary, and the key enumerator is basically sensitive to that.

The simplest fix would be just to create a copy:

```
IEnumerable<Color> colors = colorDictionary.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: As far as i know, KeyCollection has no ToList(), so I will use CopyTo and make colors a Color[].

Comment: @user1825860: No, but it implements `IEnumerable<TKey>`, so you can use the LINQ extension method `Enumerable.ToList()`. Just make sure you have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`.

Comment: Oh... oops. I edited my comment with a solution while you replied. I'll use your's though, it's better.